# meteor release 0.6.5 public/images looks like it's packaging up in the wrong directory

Tags: image, path, meteor, public

In my meteor application I create a directory public/images and then I place image files there.  Then I watch .meteor/local/build/programs/app see that I now have the new directory .meteor/local/build/programs/app/images.  the public directory is left out.  This is messing up all the image links in my application.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour. The public directory isn't there in the final bundled version or the deployed version of your app (so it also applies when developing your application). When deployed its stored alongside everything static with meteor.

This means that your files in /public/images would still be accessible at yourhost/images. (Without the name of the public folder anywhere)

Comment: So the real problem I'm having is that references to the path public/images in my html fail to work now. How would I correct that?

Answer (score 0):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1328) for this. The workaround while I waiting the answer is to declare absolute path ( which is very nasty )